# CSV to EXCEL without using any JAR

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to convert a CSV file to an Excel file using Java. The constraint is that I cannot use any JAR file so I have used POI apache Source code since i thought of importing the source code of POI jar instead of the JAR itself in my project.

What I did was, I downloaded the POI source code from the internet and the source files in  my project. It works perfectly fine in local machine but on a server it gives **InvocationTarget Exception.**

Is there any other way in which I can convert CSV to excel without any JAR.

Below is the code that converts CSV to XLS

```
  try
{
HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = hwb.createSheet("Sheet1");
for(int k=0;k<arList.size();k++)
{
ArrayList ardata = (ArrayList)arList.get(k);
// System.out.println("ardata " + ardata.size());
HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) 0+k);
for(int p=0;p<ardata.size();p++)
{
// System.out.print(ardata.get(p));
HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) p);
cell.setCellValue(ardata.get(p).toString());
}
//  System.out.println();
} 
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(output);
hwb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
// System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated");
error = "N";
}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
    error = "Y"  ;
} //main method ends
return error;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What errors did you get? What part of the [Apache POI documentation](http://poi.apache.org/) did you try following, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Hi Gagravarr:  I have repharased the question repharased for better understanding and clarity. Actually I am trying to convert CSV file to Excel file without using any JAR

Comment: Why can you not use any JAR ? Why?

Comment: What is the full exception (+ stack trace) that you get?

Comment: You can import source code as much as you want but you can't use a jar? Just out of curiousity: what is the reason behind the constraint?

Answer (score 0):

We can create XLS files without any jar. For that we need to understand the file format of XLS. XLS is a simple XML format only. i posted some XLS format sample links . Please refer the links. Then you can create the XLS file like the simple txt file.

**Reference  :**

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-an-xml-file-into-an-excel-spreadsheet-with-this-technique/

http://svn.codehaus.org/gumtree/gumtree/tags/REL-1.7.0/net.sourceforge.nattable/net/sourceforge/nattable/export/excel/excelExportHeader.txt

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats

http://jasonhaley.com/blog/post/2004/03/20/export-data-in-a-web-application-to-excel-including-formulas-for-columns.aspx